# In SwiftUI how do I refer to a view to perform a property on it?

Tags: swiftui

I have a `SearchBar` that I've added a `dismiss` property to. `dismiss` is used by the cancel button, but also might be used by the parent view when displaying a sheet. How do I define the `SearchBar` in the parent view to be able to reference the `dismiss` property?

The relevant parts of the `SearchBar` look like this:

```
struct SearchBar: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    @Binding var isSearching: Bool
    let prompt: String

    var body: some View {
        ...
    }

    var dismiss: Void {
        // dismiss the keyboard
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
        isSearching = false
        text = ""
    }
}
```

I envisioned the parent `SearchView` to look something like this:

```
struct SearchView: View {

    @State private var isShowingDataView = false
    @State private var searchText = ""
    @State private var isSearching = false
    let prompt = "Search"

    @State private var searchBar: View

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            searchBar = SearchBar(text: $searchText, isSearching: $isSearching, prompt: prompt)
            ...
            Button(action: {
                showData(data: data)
            }) {
                HStack {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func showData(data: Data) {
        dataShowing = data
        if isSearching {
            searchBar.dismiss
        }
        isShowingDataView = true
    }
}
```

With the above I get the error:
"Protocol 'View' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements"
on the `searchBar` definition line, and
"Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'"
on the `VStack` line.

Answer (score 0):

`dismiss` should be a method on your `Searchview`, and you should pass a closure to `SearchBar` for it to call when its cancel button is tapped.

```
struct SearchBar: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    let prompt: String
    let isSearching: Bool
    let cancel: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField(prompt, text: $text)
            Button("Cancel", action: cancel)
        }
        .disabled(!isSearching)
    }
}

struct SearchView: View {
    @State private var isShowingDataView = false
    @State private var searchText = ""
    @State private var isSearching = false
    let prompt = "Search"

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            SearchBar(
                text: $searchText,
                prompt: prompt,
                isSearching: $isSearching,
                cancel: self.cancelSearch
            )

            Button(action: {
                showData(data: data)
            }) {
                HStack {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func showData(data: Data) {
        dataShowing = data
        cancelSearch()
        isShowingDataView = true
    }

    private func cancelSearch() {
        guard isSearching else { return }
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
        isSearching = false
        text = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd put `dismiss` in `SearchBar` to maintain encapsulation. `SearchView` shouldn't know the details of how to cancel the `SearchBar` that are not visible on the interface, particularly dismissing the keyboard. Right now I'm borrowing your idea of passing a function, but the other direction. Have `SearchBar` pass `dismiss` (or `self`) back through a binding so it can be executed in `SearchView`, but am struggling with syntax (I'm new to Swift). Help?